# Returning the current user id along with the token when login using Token Authentication in django rest framework

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-rest-viewsets, http-token-authentication

I am using JWT token for login authentication.
When the user logs in, it returns a token. 
how can i get the user id of the logged in user along with the token?

I have tried it by using request.user. it it return AnonymousUser.

```
class LoginUser(viewsets.ViewSet):
    serializer_class = AuthTokenSerializer

    def create(self, request):
        token= ObtainAuthToken().post(request)
        username=User.objects.all(self.request.user)
        datas={token,username}
        return HttpResponse(datas)
```

i want to return the token as well as the user id.

Answer (score 1):

try `request.auth` to get the token and `request.user.id` to get the user id